# Jsoup удаление атрибута

Tags: java, jsoup

Я хочу удалить из html-документа из тега `embed` атрибут `style`:

```
<div>
    <embed class="style_5" id="__bookmark_3" onresize="document.getElementById('__bookmark_3').reload()" type="image/svg+xml" src="image/custom10.svg" alt="" style=" width: 212pt; height: 285.75pt;display: block;"></embed>
</div>
```

Для этого я использую библиотеку jsoup и следующий код:

```
File generatedReport = new File(outputReportPath);
if (generatedReport.exists()) {
    logger.info("generatedReport exists");
} else {
    logger.info("generatedReport doesn't exist");
}
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(generatedReport, "UTF-8");
Element embed = doc.select("embed").first();
String styleAttr = embed.attr("style");
logger.info("styleAttr: " + styleAttr);
embed.removeAttr("style");
```

И после запуска в логах такой вывод:

> ...|INFO | generatedReport exists
>
> ...|INFO | styleAttr:  width: 212pt; height: 285.75pt;display: block;

Т.е. вроде как всё отрабатывает хорошо, кроме того, что тег из html-файла не удаляется. Что я делаю неверно? Или данный метод только удаляет атрибут из объектной модели в памяти программы, и нужно перезаписать файл, чтобы фактически удалить атрибут из тега hmtl-файла?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, как я и предполагала, данный метод только удаляет аттрибут из объектной модели в памяти программы, и нужно перезаписать файл, чтобы фактически удалить аттрибут из тега hmtl-файла. После добавления данного кода:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(generatedReport,"UTF-8");
writer.write(doc.html());
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

html-файл был изменён, и тег embed стал выглядеть

```
<embed class="style_5" id="__bookmark_3" onresize="document.getElementById('__bookmark_3').reload()" type="image/svg+xml" src="image/custom10.svg" alt="">
```

что и требовалось.